# Extract values from pandas series column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with column of type Series.

```
id   col1
1    b'[{"code":"P16_HCAQNB","onto":"finngen","syns":["hydrocephalus acquired newborn","of newborn 
    acquired hydrocephalus","hydrocephalus, acquired, newborn","newborn acquired 
    hydrocephalus","hydrocephalus, acquired, of newborn","hydrocephalus acquired of 
    newborn","p16_hcaqnb"],"term":"Hydrocephalus, acquired, of newborn"}]'
2    b'[{"code":"OVERPROD_THYROID__HORMONE","onto":"finngen","syns":["drug induced overproduction 
   of thyroid stimulating hormone","overproduction thyroid stimulating hormone, drug 
  induced","overproduction thyroid-stimulating hormone, drug-induced","overproduction thyroid- 
 stimulating hormone drug-induced","drug-induced overproduction of thyroid-stimulating 
  hormone","drug-induced overproduction thyroid-stimulating 
  hormone","overprod_thyroid__hormone","overproduction of thyroid-stimulating hormone drug- 
 induced","overproduction of thyroid stimulating hormone, drug induced","drug induced 
 overproduction thyroid stimulating hormone","overproduction thyroid stimulating hormone drug 
 induced","overproduction of thyroid-stimulating hormone, drug-induced","overproduction of 
 thyroid stimulating hormone drug induced"],"term":"Overproduction of thyroid-stimulating 
 hormone, drug-induced"}]'
```

How can I extract value for 'code'. The final output should be:

```
id   col1
1    P16_HCAQNB
2    OVERPROD_THYROID__HORMONE
```

I have tried below code but it is not working.

```
df['col1'][0][0]

df['col1'][0][code]
```

Comment: First convert your strings to object with `ast.literal_eval`, then use the `str` accessor. `df['col1'].apply(ast.literal_eval).str[0].str['code']`

Comment: @mozway It looks to me like rshar's example dataframe contains [`bytes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal) objects. Shouldn't the first step be to decode those to obtain strings (like so: `df["col1"].str.decode("utf-8")`)?

Comment: @Xukrao yes you're right, this extra step is needed